# PHP Date (ymd) Comparison Bug

Tags: php, debugging, datetime, date

I am using a datepicker to store a unix / PHP timestamp that is selected by the user.

I just noticed that in my attempt to print `$current_date` and compare it against `$_date_compare` ... FYI this is WordPress code, but the problem is not related to WordPress.

So, that being said here's the snippet of relevant code:

```
$current_date = date('ymd');
$recentPosts = new WP_Query();
$recentPosts->query(array(
    'category_name' => 'events',
    'meta_key' => '_date_compare',
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'meta_value' => $current_date,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 99
));
```

For some reason, the result for Jan 01, 2005 is printing 50101 (leaving out the leading zero, which confuses me since I am using `date('ymd');` format for the date.

Nevertheless, after some careful thought I realized that this is a non-issue.  I'm trying to sort all events that have a HIGHER value than `$current_date`, yet the query is returning the Jan 01 2005 date in the HIGHER than `$current_date` query.

At the time of this writing, today is **110523** in `date('ymd')` format.  Why is **50101** being returned in my query that is checking for values that are **higher** than 110523?!

***EDIT*** You can view the problem here: http://anasmadance.com/past-events-2/ - The numbers printed just above the boxes are meant to be `ymd` formatted dates, which are correct for the early dates, but incorrect for the ones at the bottom of the page (which should be omitted from the query since they are past and therefore less than the value they are compared against)

Comment: Have you tried typecasting the values to int?

Comment: PHP may be casting to a numeric value and trimming the leading zero, but in an example, it doesn't seem to do this automatically. http://codepad.org/ePpg7Cuf

Comment: Have you tried `'meta_value' => "$current_date"`?

Comment: @Baez - I'm not familiar with typecasting the values to int?  Can you explain?

Comment: @Brian - an example of casting to an integer: http://codepad.org/tUKziMSi

Comment: If that's supposed to be sort ASC, I must be mightily confused. It goes from 11 to 12, then 5 to 6. Are you sure you're sorting correctly according to the WordPress documentation?

Comment: @Jared Farrish - Yup, I'm sorting correctly - you'll have to take my word for it, everything is working as expected with the exception of the "Y" value dates less than or equal to 2009. Your Codepad snippet is helpful but being a PHP novice I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: It seems like a query issue (as in the actual query presented to the DB). Have you looked at it to inspect what it's receiving? If it's not coming back from the query, it wouldn't be there to display.

Comment: And no, I don't think Baez's comment will make any difference.

Comment: @Brian, what's the date value look like when you saved it in the DB e.g. for `Jan 01, 2005`? is the column an `int`?

Comment: @Jared Farrish - weird thing is that I have two queries - one that queries future and one that queries past.  the dates <= 2009 are returning in the future query unexpectedly.  It's a mess :/  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @tradyblix - the datepicker saves the date as PHP unix timestamp.  then from that $_date_compare is extracted as the `ymd` format of that unix timestamp.

Comment: is your column an `int` for the date where you save the timestamp? can you provide a sample of the timestamp you're saving?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this may help you.  I need to see and do several debugging to know what's going on, but here is what I found by googling

try to replace $recentPosts with $wp_query and tell us what's the result.  I know this looks silly, but this is what I found claimed here:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_query-amp-pagination-not-working?replies=11
and here:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-wp_query-with-paged

if this didn't work, can you please var_dump $current_date right after it and let us know the result.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Your examples above relate to WordPress pagination but my query does not use pagination. Today is May 24, 2011 and the result of the `var_dump()` is `110524

Comment: can you post the whole result of var_dump such as string(6)"110524" or (int)..etc